# Prettyphoto stops responsive menu from appearing on mobile devices

Tags: prettyphoto

I'm wondering if anyone can advise on the following.
(I apologise in advance as I'm not over familiar with .js and prettyphoto, etc)

We have a site footiegoals.com and this utilises prettyphoto, in order to get prettyphoto to work on the website on the pictures I had to comment out the lines as shown below.

Prettyphoto then works fine. However the responsive menu does not display if the screen is resized or if its viewed from a mobile device

Im assuming its a conflict of sorts between the version of .js used ?

Is there any way to fix this does anyone know?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="prettyphoto/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marmelad' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.quicksand.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.quovolver.js"></script>


<!-- These lines commented out
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">   
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/script.js"></script>

These lines commented out 
```

Thank you

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the latest version and added the uncommented lines back and it appears to now be working.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">   
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```